# How to automatically set a <td>'s height to fill up maximum space?

Tags: css

The answer is probably something very simple, seems CSS positioning is a weak point for me.

I'd like a `<td>` cell to take up the entire height of it's parent `<tr>`, so that it looks like this:
[image]

For this example, I'm trying to get `col1` to have the same height as `col2`, which is **unknown and varies**. I'd like `col1`'s **two children** to be positioned at the top and bottom of the cell, presumably using `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column`, and `justify-content: space-between`. However this doesn't produce the result I'd like because `col1`'s height is only fitting it's own content, not the height of it's parent.

To my knowledge, I'd assume `height: 100%` would get `col1`'s height to take up the space provided, but that isn't working.

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.col1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

table {
  background-color: blue;
}

p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">
        <p>col1 content</p>
        <p>col1 content</p>
      </td>
      <td class="col2">
        <p>col2 content</p>
        <p>col2 content</p>
        <p>col2 content</p>
        <p>col2 content</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t get it to work either. I don’t know the technical details, and I don’t know what kind of content you want to display. But I do know that you should only use tables for tabular data, not for general layout. From the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-table-element):

> Tables must not be used as layout aids. Historically, some web authors
> have misused tables in HTML as a way to control their page layout.

However, I have found some alternatives for you. Hopefully one of these will work:

(1) You can use a grid instead of a table

```css
.d1 {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 2px;
  gap: 2px;
}

.d1>* {
  background-color: red;
}

.col1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
    <div class="col1">
      <p>col1 content</p>
      <p>col1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <p>col2 content</p>
      <p>col2 content</p>
      <p>col2 content</p>
      <p>col2 content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

(2) You can use absolute positioning if you are sure that overlapping won't be a problem

```css
table {
  background-color: blue;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.col1 {
  position: relative;
}

.col1>*:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">
        <p>col1 content</p>
        <p>col1 content</p>
      </td>
      <td class="col2">
        <p>col2 content</p>
        <p>col2 content</p>
        <p>col2 content</p>
        <p>col2 content</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

(3) You can pad the content with blank paragraphs so the sizes match

```css
table {
  background-color: blue;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">
        <p>col1 content</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>col1 content</p>
      </td>
      <td class="col2">
        <p>col2 content</p>
        <p>col2 content</p>
        <p>col2 content</p>
        <p>col2 content</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are right, using tables for UI has given me nothing but nightmares.

Solution #1 seems perfect! I really need to block out some time to learn grid.

Solution #2 seems viable, but when I apply it to my specific issue, a mess of overlapping occurs. Clearly I've dug myself into a hole with this code.

Solution #3 wouldn't be ideal, since (as mentioned) the content in cell #2 varies, so I would like this behavior to work regardless of what is added/removed to cell #2.